# Flutter Riverpod alternative to a _provider.when

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

Looking for an alternative to

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final _user = useProvider(MyUserProvider);
       ...
return _user.when(data: data, loading: loading, error: error)
```

for most of my components

I want to use sth like

```
final _user = useProvider(MyUserProvider);
// then
return Text(_user.name)
```

directly because the firebase user data stream is already in the tree and can never be null or have an error.

1. Can I use a ChangeNotifier to achieve this ?
2. How else can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```dart
final authStream = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) => ref.watch(FirebaseAuth.instance).authStateChanges());

final user = Provider<User?>((ref) => ref.watch(authStream).data?.value);
```

Then:

```dart
final _user = useProvider(user);
return Text(_user?.name ?? '');
// or if you're sure the value is not null or your app relies on it being not null
return Text(_user!.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new provider which will depend from the precedent :

```
final connectedUserProvider = Provider<User>((ref) {
  final userState = ref.watch(MyUserProvider.state);
  return userState.maybeWhen(data: (User user) => user, orElse: () => throw "you should not be there");
});
```

Comment: `MyUserProvider` is a `StreamProvider`. How do I plug it in ?